# Unexpected Error

Tags: android

So I can't figure out why my app wont load... There are no errors.

[Link to onCreate (Its kinda big)](http://pastebin.com/ssXXhiWw)

Maybe it has to do with tabhost? new to that, first attempt...

Hopefully someone can help.

Thanks,
Brandon

Comment: You serisouly need to refactor that code :)

Comment: @Brandon : first I'd start with using loops to load the resources. To debug your application did you open the DDMS perspective? Please check the Log, the information you need is there!

Comment: How would I go about loading with loops? How would I tell which resource to load... like I understand loops... but how would I tell the loop to load the next resource, is there a method to get it as an array?

sorry if I worded that weird...
I am debugging through DDMS (didnt know about it till now haha)

Comment: 01-01 15:30:54.346: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(453): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.laytproducts.girboardpro/com.laytproducts.girboardpro.mainAct}: java.lang.NullPointerException


             now I am confused

Comment: You need to post the rest of your code. You are not showing us where you are instantiating (creating) the objects sound as mSoundManager.

Comment: I fixed it. It was a lot of errors with the Tab Hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet that `mSoundManager` is null. Where are you initializing it ?
Most probably you should initialize if before using it as it seems to depend on `Context`.

Comment: I finally got it to work... But now I am getting Heap Size Overflow errors... I have like 86 sounds in my sound pool... But they are all small oggs so I am surprised I am having issues with this. Is there anyway to bypass this? Maybe its just the emulator having crudy heap sizes?